# Is it correct to use one directive once in one component?

Tags: vue.js

According to the recommendation of the Vue directive, it is recommended to use the directive in general cases for many components. How can I then correctly remake for example such a directive, which is used only once in the one component.

```html
dropped(el, binding, vnode) {
      if (vnode.context.isDropped) {
        el.style.height =
          el.firstChild.scrollHeight+
          "px";
      } else {
        el.style.height = 0;
      }
    },
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly what your question is. A directive can be used as many or as few times as you would like. The code you shared isn't very clear either. It looks like a directive, but `dropped` is not part of that interface. Can you give some more details? What are you trying to do? What have you tried so far? What issues are you running into?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it correct to use one directive once in one component?

You would need to define correct in regards to *what*, but no it does not pose a problem. You can use a directive as much or little as you like.

**However** since your asking about code style, if your directive is going to be used only on one component, why not put it directly in the component's code?

Comment: This directive sets the height of the element equal to the height of the child if the condition is true.

Comment: You can do it in the component directly then @Serio